# Should I check if `[managedObjectContext hasChanges]` before saving?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

```
// Save changes if any.
NSError *error;
if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    // TODO: handle this error better.
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends. If you're sure that changes have been made to the `managedObjectContext`, then there's no need to check. However, if there's any possibility that changes have not been made, then you should check before saving.

Check out the [application delegate of the CoreDataBooks Xcode sample app](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CoreDataBooks/Listings/Classes_CoreDataBooksAppDelegate_m.html) for examples of both these scenarios.